# How to simplify the conditional expectation $E[v_3\mid v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\}, v_3=\max\{v_2,v_3\}]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are three random variables drawn independently from the same distribution $\mathrm{uniform}(0,1)$, is it correct that
 $$E[v_3\mid v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\}, v_3=\max\{v_2,v_3\}] = E[\max\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}]\ ?$$

Comment: Could you give us your reasoning on why it might be true?  It would be easier for us to help you if we knew where you were stuck.

Comment: There is a **lot** of information you have about the question that you have not provided, beginning with, how did you come across this question? and going on to, do you understand all the terms in the question, such as "random variable", "independently", "uniform $(0,1)$, $E_3$, $E$. Anyway, you've had an answer, and you have accepted that answer, so what is the problem?

Comment: It is the place to post it, but please edit in what you have tried.

Comment: Please don't deface your question.

Comment: Please vote down. I realized this question has caused unhappiness to everyone because it's too stupid.

Comment: A shortcut is to note that $A=\{v_1 < \max\{v_2,v_3\}, v_3=\max\{v_2,v_3\}\}$ is $A=\{v_3=w\}$, where $w=\max\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, hence the expectation to be computed is $(\ast)=E(w\mid A)$. By symmetry, $w$ and $A$ are independent hence $(\ast)=E(w)$, QED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; though not in general, it *is* the case for *identical and independent distributions* (iid). (Sorry, missed that in the first reading.)

$$\mathsf E[V_3\mid V_1<\max\{V_2,V_3\}, V_3=\max\{V_2, V_3\}] \;=\; \mathsf E[V_3\mid V_3=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}]$$

This is not *necessarily* the same thing as $\mathsf E[\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}]$

Indeed:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}] \; &= \; {\mathsf E[V_1\mid V_1=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}]\;\mathsf P(V_1=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}) + \\ \; \mathsf E(V_2\mid V_2=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}] \;\mathsf P(V_2=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}) + \\ \; \color{blue}{\mathsf E(V_3\mid V_3=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}]} \;\mathsf P(V_3=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\})}\end{align}$$

*However*, in the case of iid random variables, symmetry means that all three of these probability terms evaluate to $1/3$ and all the expection terms are equal, so:

$$\mathsf E[\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}] \; = \; \mathsf E(V_3\mid V_3=\max\{V_1,V_2, V_3\}]$$

Comment: Hi Graham thx for your answer. But I was confused because isn't it true that by symmetry here we do have $E(V3∣V3=max{V1,V2,V3}]$$=E(V1∣V1=max{V1,V2,V3}]$$=E(V2∣V2=max{V1,V2,V3}]$? Also symmetry implies that $P(V3=max{V1,V2,V3})$$=P(V1=max{V1,V2,V3})$$=P(V2=max{V1,V2,V3})$ right?

Comment: @Larry; Ah.  Identical distribution.  Yes, *if* that's the case *then* symmetry holds.  Sorry.